# HSM: Intraction with HSM using JAVA application

Tags: java, security, hsm, java-security

HSM server and client setup has done at my side, And my question is How to communicate with HSM server with out HSM client to access the Luna key store through java application, Does it have any alternate to communicate with HSM server without client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use safenet SDK to develop your crypto functions which can interact with HSM from java. eg: Gemalto HSM provides JSP and JCProv API's as a part of SDK for java developers.

Answer (score 2):

You need a Luna client to an application to connect with the HSM to process crypto operations. Luna client contains the libraries that are required for a client to talk to the HSM.

Answer (score 1):

Following command show how to send command to Thales HSM.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ThalesHSMConnect2 {

    //@formatter:off
    public static final String send(final String command) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        try(final Socket sc = new Socket(host, port);
            final DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
            final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream())) {
            sc.setSoTimeout(5000);
            dos.writeUTF(command);
            dos.flush();
            final String response = din.readUTF();
            return response;
        }
    }

    public static final byte[] send(final byte[] command) throws Exception {
        try(Socket sc = new Socket(host, port);
            InputStream in = sc.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = sc.getOutputStream()) {
            sc.setSoTimeout(5000);
            command[0] = (byte) ((command.length-2)/256); //two byte command length
            command[1] = (byte) ((command.length-2)%256); //two byte command length
            os.write(command); 
            os.flush();
            final byte b1 = (byte) in.read();
            final byte b2 = (byte) in.read();
            if(b1 < 0 || b2 < 0) throw new SocketTimeoutException("no response from hsm.");
            final byte[] response = new byte[b1*256+b2];
            in.read(response);
            return response;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String cvvGenerationResponse = send("0000CWAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB4484070020000310;2105000");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code show how to prepare and send a command to safenet HSM.

```
public static final String send(String command) {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(HSMIP, HSMPORT);
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] commandbytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(command);
        byte[] request = new byte[6 + commandbytes.length];
        request[0] = 0x01;  //constant as per setting during installation
        request[1] = 0x01;  //constant as per setting during installation
        request[2] = 0x00;  //constant as per setting during installation
        request[3] = 0x00;  //constant as per setting during installation
        request[4] = (byte) (commandbytes.length / 256);  //length of command
        request[5] = (byte) (commandbytes.length % 256);  //length of command
        System.arraycopy(commandbytes, 0, request, 6, commandbytes.length);
        //logger.info("request : " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(request));
        os.write(request);
        os.flush();
        byte[] header = new byte[6];
        in.read(header);
        logger.info("header : " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(header));
        int len = (header[4] & 0xFF) * 256 + (header[5] & 0xFF);  //length of response
        logger.info("len : " + len);
        byte[] response = new byte[len];
        in.read(response);
        logger.info("response : " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(response));
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```